# What is the datatype of the parameter that we send in the header of a nodejs program?

Tags: node.js

I am writing an API in node js, for which I have the following code block:

```
app.get('/api/posts/:year/:month',(req,res)=>{

    res.send(req.params.year);

});
```

I want to know what is the datatype of `req.params.year`? Is it by default string?

Comment: It will be a string. I don't think this is a question for StackOverflow really, you could have checked it out yourself.

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan Thanks Kiran. Just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Have added it as an answer in case somebody else has the same question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters in URL which are accessible by `req.params` wouldn't have any particular datatype other than string because it is a part of the URL AFAIK.

You might have to inference the datatype from the data to get it.